# How to reload page without resetting tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm using javascript to create some automation action in a website. I know that chrome console would be reset when we hit the refresh button, so I'm trying to manage it by Tampermonkey so the script can run individually from the chrome console.

But my issue still there, tampermonkey userscript still reset when page is reloaded. Can you help me with those problem? Many thanks! p/s I'm an amateur in this coding subject so it is grateful if you guys can give me a hand :)

A part of my script is look like this:

```
var $balance = $("#balance"),
  $statusBar = $(".progress #banner");

function getStatus() {
  var a = $statusBar.text();
  if (hasSubString(a, "Rolling in")) return "waiting";
  if (hasSubString(a, "***ROLLING***")) return "rolling";
  if (hasSubString(a, "rolled")) {    
var b = parseInt(a.split("rolled")[1]);
return lastRollColor = getColor(b), "rolled"
  }
return "unknown"
}
   function getBalance() {
  return parseInt($balance.text())
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The TamperMonkey script will indeed also reset when the page is reloaded. However, you can save the state between reloads so that your script can continue where it left off.

You can use the [`GM_getValue`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_getValue) and [`GM_setValue`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setValue) functions to store data in some Tampermonkey data store, so that it is available the next time the script runs. Note that you need to use the [`@grant`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant) header to use those functions.

For example, the following script keeps the value of `counter` between reloads:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         HttpBin reload
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Reload something a couple of times
// @author       Sjoerd
// @match        https://httpbin.org/get
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var i = GM_getValue('counter', 0);
    GM_setValue('counter', i + 1);

    if (i < 5) {
        location.reload();
    }
})();
```

Comment: This seems to persist across pages. E.g. say you have a script running on https://fakesite.it/* and you set the counter on https://fakesite.it/food and visit https://fakesite.it/eat, no reloads seem to occur. Or, if you want to revisit fakesite.it/food again later, no reloads occur.

Comment: FYI, GM_getValue and GM_setValue are deprecated. It's now GM.getValue and GM.setValue

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)?

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding whatever it is you are trying to save to the `localStorage` of the page and whenever you need whatever you just saved, you can just get it from the `localStorage`.

Here are 2 commands to do so:

1. `localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);`
2. `localStorage.getItem(keyName);`

For more info check these 2 links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem